# Simple: How to replace "all between" with php?

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

```
$string = "<tag>i dont know what is here</tag>"
$string = str_replace("???", "<tag></tag>", $string);
echo $string; // <tag></tag>
```

So what code am i looking for?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$search = "/[^<tag>](.*)[^<\/tag>]/";
$replace = "your new inner text";
$string = "<tag>i dont know what is here</tag>";
echo preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
```

outputs:

```
<tag>your new inner text</tag>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want to replace the contents of the tags, and not just replace the entire string.

Comment: Should use lookaround instead, to be honest.

Comment: Running this code as is I get `Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 't' on line 1`

Comment: I'd add a `?` to the capture group, `(.*?)` to make sure the wildcard operator doesn't get to greedy and stops and the end tag next end tag.

Comment: This answer is 100% incorrect.  It is only happenstance that it provides the desired output. Watch this answer fail when the input changes slightly.  https://3v4l.org/p507L  This is an incorrect use of negated character classes and it is misinforming researchers. @faq

Comment: If you feel there is a better answer provide it, but I would be far from saying this answer is "100% incorrect" when it does exactly what it needs to do at the time it was written (and OP clearly agreed).

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect because it works only for the given example. For an input like this: $string = "BEGIN <tag>i dont know what is here</tag> MIDDLE <tag>i dont know what is here</tag> END"; you get a wrong result. For a correct solution you should use this code:
    $search = "/[^<tag>](.*)[^<\/tag>]/";
    $search = '#(<tag>).*?(</tag>)#';
    $replace = "new text";
    $string = "BEGIN <tag>inside tag</tag> MIDDLE <tag>second tag</tag> END";
    echo preg_replace($search, '$1'.$replace.'$2', $string); Link to code: https://3v4l.org/pD61r

Comment: How to handle it for case insensitive? For example <ExtendContent></ExtendContent> and <extendContent></extendContent>

Answer (score 34):

A generic function:

```
function replace_between($str, $needle_start, $needle_end, $replacement) {
    $pos = strpos($str, $needle_start);
    $start = $pos === false ? 0 : $pos + strlen($needle_start);

    $pos = strpos($str, $needle_end, $start);
    $end = $pos === false ? strlen($str) : $pos;

    return substr_replace($str, $replacement, $start, $end - $start);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/tWyiffC5)

Comment: better than the accepted answer. no need to use a regex replace unless you need one.

Comment: @sgroves Regex is a reasonable tool when it avoids code convolution or provides another sensible advantage.

Comment: I tried this in PHP 7 but no result was echoed, it seems it is also stripping out the tags - also I wonder if there is an option for all occurrences, ie more than 1 set of tags with text between

Answer (score 14):

```
$string = "<tag>I do not know what is here</tag>";
$new_text = 'I know now'; 
echo preg_replace('#(<tag.*?>).*?(</tag>)#', '$1'.$new_text.'$2' , $string); //<tag>I know now</tag>
```

Comment: You are missing replace string in second argument: '$1'.'new text'.'$2'

Answer (score 4):

If "tag" changes:

```
$string = "<tag>i dont know what is here</tag>";
$string = preg_replace('|^<([a-z]*).*|', '<$1></$1>', $string)
echo $string; // <tag></tag>
```

Comment: Watch this unexplained answer destroy more content than it should: https://3v4l.org/HBRYV

Comment: Answer without context.

Answer (score 4):

**A generic and non-regex solution:**

I've modified @felix-kling's answer. Now it only replaces text if it finds the needles.

Also, I've added parameters for replacing the needles, starting position and replacing all the matches.

I've used the `mb_` functions for making the function multi-byte safe.
If you need a case insensitive solution then replace `mb_strpos` calls with `mb_stripos`.

```
function replaceBetween($string, $needleStart, $needleEnd, $replacement,
                        $replaceNeedles = false, $startPos = 0, $replaceAll = false) {
    $posStart = mb_strpos($string, $needleStart, $startPos);

    if ($posStart === false) {
        return $string;
    }

    $start = $posStart + ($replaceNeedles ? 0 : mb_strlen($needleStart));
    $posEnd = mb_strpos($string, $needleEnd, $start);

    if ($posEnd === false) {
        return $string;
    }

    $length = $posEnd - $start + ($replaceNeedles ? mb_strlen($needleEnd) : 0);

    $result = substr_replace($string, $replacement, $start, $length);

    if ($replaceAll) {
        $nextStartPos = $start + mb_strlen($replacement) + mb_strlen($needleEnd);

        if ($nextStartPos >= mb_strlen($string)) {
            return $result;
        }

        return replaceBetween($result, $needleStart, $needleEnd, $replacement, $replaceNeedles, $nextStartPos, true);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

```
$string = "{ Some} how it {is} here{";

echo replaceBetween($string, '{', '}', '(hey)', true, 0, true); // (hey) how it (hey) here{
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = "<tag>i dont know what is here</tag>"
$string = "<tag></tag>";
echo $string; // <tag></tag>
```

---

or just?

```
$string = str_replace($string, "<tag></tag>", $string);
```

Sorry, could not resist. Maybe you update your question with a few more details. ;)

Comment: Totally unnecessary to put such words into an answer. A comment would have done it too.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know what's inside the `<tag>` tag, it's possible there is another `<tag>` tag in there e.g.

```
<tag>something<tag>something else</tag></tag>
```

And so a generic string replace function won't do the job.

A more robust solution is to treat the string as XML and manipulate it with `DOMDocument`. Admittedly this only works if the string is valid as XML, but I still think it's a better solution than a string replace.

```
$string = "<tag>i don't know what is here</tag>";
$replacement = "replacement";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($str1);
$node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tag')->item(0);
$newNode = $doc->createElement("tag", $replacement); 
$node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);
echo $str1 = $doc->saveHTML($node); //output: <tag>replacement</tag>
```

Comment: This almost a working answer.  I made some adjustments. https://3v4l.org/phEOf  Overall, if DomDocument can be used, it should be used for stability.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to replace the  portion too then this function is helpful:

```
$var = "Nate";

$body = "Hey there {firstName} have you already completed your purchase?";

$newBody = replaceVariable($body,"{","}",$var);

echo $newBody;

function replaceVariable($body,$needleStart,$needleEnd,$replacement){
  while(strpos($body,$needleStart){
      $start = strpos($body,$needleStart);
      $end = strpos($body,$needleEnd);
      $body = substr_replace($body,$replacement,$start,$end-$start+1);
  }
  return $body;
}
```

I had to replace a variable put into a textarea that was submitted. So I replaced firstName with Nate (including the curly braces).

Comment: This works great, without regular expressions. But only if you want to replace only one occurence of the string. If you need to replace multiple occurence, you must do a loop until strpos will return FALSE (which means there isn't any occurence to replace any more.

Comment: **Note**: this expression `strpos($body,$needleEnd);` would start the search from the beginning of the string. To search from the start needle you will need an offset: `strpos($body,$needleEnd, $needleStart);`.