# PHP: Replace the content between two characters, in multiple occurrences

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace the contents between some "special" characters, in each of their occurrences. For example, let's say i have that string:

```
<div><small>static content</small><small>[special content type 3]</small> 
<small>static content</small><small>[special content type 4]</small></div>
```

I would like to replace each "special content", between square brackets, with something that is represented by this "identifier"(let's say, some "widget").

I've tried this code from Stackoverflow:

```
$search = "/[^<tag>](.*)[^<\/tag>]/";
$replace = "your new inner text";
$string = "<tag>i dont know what is here</tag>";
echo preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
```

This works, but only for the first occurrence. I need this operation to be repeated across the entire string.

I've also tried this one:

```
echo preg_replace('/<div class="username">.+?</div>/im', '<div 
class="username">Special Username<\/div>', $string) ;
```

It gives me a "Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'd' in Standard input code on line 8" error.

Any ideas?

Comment: sth like this: https://regex101.com/r/geF7pU/1/ `\[([^\]]*)\]` ?

Comment: Expected output is not clear.

Comment: If you are parsing HTML, use a DOM parser instead of regex.  The `m` pattern modifier doesn't do anything in your coding attempt.

Comment: Please don't try [answers which have comments under them saying that the answer us 100% incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6875963/2943403).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code from stackoverflow needs minor changes:

```
$search = "/(<tag>)(.*?)(<\/tag>)/";
$replace = '$1your new inner text$3';
$string = "<tag>i dont know what is here</tag> some text <tag>here's another one</tag>";
echo preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
```

Comment: Any idea why this `$search = "/([PAID_JOB])(.*?)([\/PAID_JOB])/";` doesnt work?

Comment: @Ingus you need to escape the `[` and `]` as they are special characters for regex.

Comment: That doesnt seems to be working `$search = "/(\[tag\])(.*?)(\[\/tag\])/";`

Comment: @Ingus if you are having problems, ask a question. Comments are not the place for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
function replace_all_text_between($str, $start, $end, $replacement) {

    $replacement = $start . $replacement . $end;

    $start = preg_quote($start, '/');
    $end = preg_quote($end, '/');
    $regex = "/({$start})(.*?)({$end})/";

    return preg_replace($regex,$replacement,$str);
}
```