# How to replace (.) dots by (·) interpuncts in PHP?

Tags: php, typography, punctuation

There's a French typographic rule to write properly some words in a genderless way, by adding an (·) interpunct between letters.
A few authors on my website are however typing a simple (.) dot instead.

As a solution, I'd like to create a function to replace in PHP strings each dots which are placed between two lowercase letters by interpuncts. But my PHP skills are rather limited… Here is what I'm looking for:

**REPLACE THIS**:

`$string = "T.N.T.: Chargé.e des livreur.se.s."`

**BY THIS**:

`$string = "T.N.T.: Chargé·e des livreur·se·s."`

Could someone help me please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `preg_replace` with pattern to dynamically match 3 groups - two lowercase letters (including special French letters) and dot between, and use the first and third captured group in replacement, along with intepunct:

```
$string = "T.N.T.: Chargé.e des livreur.se.s.";
$pattern = '/([a-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñæœ])(\.)([a-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñæœ])/';
$replacement = '$1·$3'; //captured first and third group, and interpunct in the middle 

//results in "T.N.T.: Chargé·e des livreur·se·s."
$string_replaced = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

More about `preg_replace`:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_replace()` if you know the grammar rules surrounding the dots you want to replace. (for instance, if everything between `é`and `e` is concerned, then you can do :

```
$bodytag = str_replace("é.e", "é·e", $sourceText);
```

But you will always risk some side effects. For instance if there is an acronym you don't want to be replaced with this pattern. I don't think there is any magic way to avoid this.

More specifically

> I'd like to create a function to replace in PHP strings each dots which are placed between two lowercase letters by interpuncts.

This can be achieved with `preg_replace()` and the appropriate REGEX

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875913/simple-how-to-replace-all-between-with-php)