# Change hardcoded ids in javascript file

Tags: php, regex, replace, hardcoded

I have to parse a javascript file and replace the last function parameter every time a specific function is called.  I have an array of replacement values that supplies the new ids.

Javascript code:

```
// every time this function is called I need to replace change_id with different value from array
function submitData(element_id, url, change_id) {...
    ...
}

... 

// I want to replace 3, 2 and 4 with values from my array
// 3,2,4 are just used for example, values are dynamic
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { submitData(1, "http://mysite/metrics, 3");}); window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { submitData(1, "http://mysite/metrics, 2");}); window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { submitData(1, "http://mysite/metrics, 4");});
```

I have an array of ids, and I would like to loop through them and replace the value in each function call with one of the values from this array

My array:

```
$change_ids = [10,15,20];
```

So the result should be:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { submitData(1, "http://mysite/metrics, 10");}); window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { submitData(1, "http://mysite/metrics, 15");}); window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { submitData(1, "http://mysite/metrics, 20");});
```

Only third parameter in function call needs to be changed, so I thought about using something like this(found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6875963/7657853)):

```
$search = "/[^metrics,](.*)[^\"\)]/";
$replace = "10";
$string = file_get_contents($pathToJsFile);
echo preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
```

But the problem is that `$change_id` will be equal in every function call

Comment: Try https://3v4l.org/YH3l7, `$search = '/\bmetrics,\s*\K.*?(?="\))/'; $change_ids_copy = $change_ids; echo preg_replace_callback($search,function($m) use (&$change_ids_copy) {
    return array_shift($change_ids_copy);
},$string);`

Comment: Just an idea. Seem to bi kind a dirty but, you could get all function calls with regex separate them in 3 variables and then replace each value separately and then get all back together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this solution:

```
$javascript = file_get_contents($path);
if (empty($javascript)) {
   return false;
}
$search = '/(?<=metrics\",)\s*.*?(?=\))/';
```

This pattern will return " 1"(whitespace 1) from this string:

> window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { submitData(1,
> "http://mysite/metrics", **1**);});

After that I replace the match with value from my array.

```
$javascript = preg_replace_callback($search,function($m) use (&$change_ids) {  
    $m = $m[key($m)];
    $m = ' '. array_shift($change_ids);
    return $m;
},$javascript);
        
return file_put_contents($path, $javascript);
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* avoid a native function call by converting your javascript string into a "template" with `%d` placeholders, then simply inject your new ids into those placeholders with `vsprintf()` (I'll demonstrate with `vprintf()` so that the string is printed to the screen).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MLOSN))

```
$string = <<<JS
function submitData(element_id, url, change_id) {...
    ...
}

... 
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { submitData(1, "http://mysite/metrics, 3");}); window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { submitData(1, "http://mysite/metrics, 2");}); window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { submitData(1, "http://mysite/metrics, 4");});
JS;

$change_ids = [19, 7, 11];

vprintf(
    preg_replace('~metrics,\s*\K\d+~', '%d', $string),
    $change_ids
);
```